# MPI IO very slow. What could be the cause?

Tags: c, openmpi

I have just converted a program to make use of MPI calls for use on multiple nodes but I am having a problem getting IO to work well with MPI calls.

I am using standard MPI2 IO Methods like MPI_File_open and MPI_File_write to write my final results to a file. On my laptop, I experience a slight speedup (0.2s -> 0.1s) but on the University's super computer my file writing speed becomes abysmal - (0.2s -> 90s!).

I cant understand why performance would be so bad on the supercomputer but improved on my desktop. Is there something I am overlooking which would heavily contribute to the slow speed?

Some Notes:

- The file system on my laptop is *ext4* and the one used by the University is *nfs*
- I am using *OpenMP 1.4.4* on the super computer and *OpenMP 1.4.5* on my laptop.
- I have the change the processes view multiple times using MPI_File_set_view due to a requirement set in the guidelines which I dont think I can get past.
- I have tried using the asynchronous version of write -MPI_File_iwrite, but this actually gives *worse* results.

Comment: If the supercomputer uses nfs, then it's going over a network and that is very likely to be slower than a local hard disk.

Comment: I understand that, but 90 seconds? If I dont use MPI IO calls and just use standard fopen I get about 0.2 seconds.

Comment: How much data are you writing?

Comment: About 281kb per process